# git-svn - cloned a single branch, now dcommit to another branch?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have been using git-svn to work remotely on a spike for a new feature. Now I want to commit my changes to SVN, but on a *different SVN branch than the one I first cloned*. How do I do that ?

The original branch has changed, and I am not ready to merge the two. I would like to create a new SVN branch from the original branch, and commit the changes I have in git.

I have a shallow clone of just the one SVN branch:

```
git svn clone -r:HEAD svn://***/branches/main
git branch MySpike
git checkout MySpike
// Did some work, a lot of commits.
```

How do I commit my changes back to another SVN branch ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I'd say 1: check out the target SVN branch with git-svn and make it your working copy (create it if it doesn't exist). 2: git-merge or git-rebase your local MySpike branch into the tracking branch. 2b (optional): delete the MySpike branch, because all the hashes change after you dcommit and git will no longer be able to tell that it has been merged. 3: dcommit the tracking branch to the SVN repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [the.malkolm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631276/the-malkolm)'s answer:

If you look in `.git/config`, you'll find a line like `fetch = branches/main:refs/remotes/git-svn`. Add another similar line, referring to the name of the remote branch you want to commit to, and a name to give it locally (or, for the Subversion trunk, `fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk`).

Then run `git svn fetch`. That'll download the history of the branch you've just added; feel free to limit the revisions it fetches if that's what you need.

Then rebase onto the new branch, and commit from there!

```
git rebase $(git merge-base remotes/git-svn MySpike) MySpike --onto remotes/newbranch
git svn dcommit
```

Answer (score 1):

After you managed to configure two svn branches (just modify .git/config file). Here is how to rebase all code you did on top of *svn/original/branch* in the branch named *cool/feature* to another svn branch *svn/another/branch*:

```
git rebase --onto svn/another/branch $(git merge-base svn/original/branch cool/feature) cool/feature
```